# How are request parameters sent via <apex:actionFunction> component

Tags: visualforce, visualforce-component, ajax

when we use **apex:param** inside an **apex:actionFunction** component as given below

```
<apex:page controller="testCon">
<apex:outputText value="Clicked? {!state}" id="showstate" />
<apex:outputPanel onclick="methodOneInJavascript('Yes!')" styleClass="btn">
    Click Me
</apex:outputPanel>
<apex:form>
    <apex:actionFunction action="{!methodOne}" name="methodOneInJavascript" rerender="showstate">
        <apex:param name="firstParam" assignTo="{!state}" value="" />
    </apex:actionFunction>
</apex:form>
```

```
public class testCon {

    public void setState(String n) {
        state = n;
    }

    public String getState() {
        return state;
    }

    public PageReference methodOne() {
        return null;
    }

    private String state = 'no';
}
```

How will be the request parameter *firstParam* sent to the controller when an Ajax request happens? Is it via **query string parameter** or in the **body** of the request (as in POST request) ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you declare an `actionFunction` a javascript function name equal to actionFunction's attribute `name` named is declared and initialised on rendered visualforce page.

Ex:

```
<apex:actionFunction action="{!methodOne}" name="methodOneInJavascript" rerender="showstate">
        <apex:param name="firstParam" assignTo="{!state}" value="" />
</apex:actionFunction>
```

Above code will rendered as:

```
var methodOne = function(firstParam, otherConfigParams) {

// Ajax implemetation

}
```

and when you call this `actionfunction` by `apex:commandButton` or by any other method it sends `post` request to visualforce page url and the request url seems like:

```
https://www.salesforcedomain/apex/vfpagemae
```

and the Ajax request constructed ( Body ) as:

```
com.salesforce.visualforce.ViewState: "i:COMPLETE VIEWSTATE"
com.salesforce.visualforce.ViewStateCSRF: "SecurityChecks"
com.salesforce.visualforce.ViewStateMAC: "AJUrHNkMoCfHaWCeqkFxDJVJ2D+b"
com.salesforce.visualforce.ViewStateVersion: "201310242028360004"
j_id0:j_id9: "j_id0:j_id9" // FORM_ID
j_id0:j_id9:j_id10: "j_id0:j_id9:j_id10"
firstParam: "VALUE_SENDING"
```

So each request send by actionFunction is **POST** request and content sent is exist in **body**.

We cannot say that request is sent like https://www.salesforcedomain/apex/vfpagemae?Params=abcdf and page can only get params through it.

Basically Salesforce has its own way and it assign all values to **MAP** `ApexPages.CurrentPage().getParametrs()` either it recieved from **Query URL String** or from **body**.

Answer (score 7):

So when you are using a actionFunction there are two ways you can access the value from the controller.

- You can use the **assignTo** attribute of the apex:param to set a variable in the controller.
- You can use `Apexpages.Currentpage().getParameters().get('yourParamName')`

For your question

> How will be the request parameter firstParam sent to the controller
>   when an Ajax request happens? Is it via query string parameter or in
>   the body of the request (as in POST request) ?

If you check the option "2" we can retrieve the value of the param using URL parameter. So the Answer is it is Send via **Query Parameters**

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a public attribute in the controller.

This attr should have getter and setter.

```
public String state {get; set;}
```

Comment: Martin, I have declared the variable state with explicit getter and setter methods.